# wagtail, Failed to import images uploaded from the wagtail administrator console to the page

Tags: django, wagtail

Failed to import images uploaded from the wagtail administrator console to the page.
Image title is being loaded properly, but image url is not being loaded.

[image]

```
#home/models.py
from django.db import models
from wagtail.models import Page
from wagtail.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel


class HomePage(Page):
    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    body_detail = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('header_image'),
        FieldPanel('body'),
        FieldPanel('body_detail'),
    ]
```

```
#home_page.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/welcome_page.css' %}">

<div class="container">
    {% if page.header_image %}
    <img src="{{ page.header_image.url }}" alt="{{ page.header_image.title }}">
    {% endif %}
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    {{ page.body|richtext }}

    <div class="homebtn_intro">
        <a href="{% slugurl 'about' %}"> <img src="{{ page.image.url }}" alt="hello"> </a>
        <a href="{% slugurl 'about' %}"> <img src="" alt="registration"> </a>
        <a href="{% slugurl 'about' %}"> <img src="" alt="donation"> </a>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Checked the path where the image is stored and verify that template language is created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to use images in Wagtail is through [the `{% image %}` template tag](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/images.html). This lets you specify the dimensions to render the image at, meaning that you aren't reliant on your content authors uploading images at the correct size:

```
{% if page.header_image %}
    {% image page.header_image fill-800x400 %}
{% endif %}
```

Since Image objects aren't intended to be used directly on pages, they don't provide a `url` property, which is why your template code doesn't work.